# R create graphs of average in time difference

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a big `data.table` that contains the following cols:

```
timestamp, value, house
```

The value is a cumulative value of eg energy of that one house. So here is a small sample:

```
               time value house
2014-10-27 11:40:00   100     2
2014-10-27 15:40:00   150     2
2014-10-27 19:40:30   160     2
2014-10-28 00:00:01   170     2
2014-10-28 20:20:20   180     2
2014-10-27 11:40:00   200     3
2014-10-27 15:40:00   300     3
2014-10-27 19:40:30   400     3
2014-10-28 00:00:01   500     3
2014-10-28 20:20:20   600     3
```

I want to get 3 bar charts: one with the average per house usage per hour of a day, one with the average per house usage per day of a week, and the average per house usage per month of a year.

To get the value of one hour of one day, I guess I should do something like

```
max(data$value) - min(data$value)
```

, but that per time interval of an hour and also per house. I know `cut(data$time, breaks="hour")` splits it up in intervals, but of course does not take the difference of the maximum and minimum value and also doesn't consider the house it is from. On top of that I would also need the average of course.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you need to do a lot of interpolation? Ie, do you not actually have the cumulative usage at each hour?

Comment: I have a lot of data points - a short skim through one of my files has 10000 entries for one single day, it depends on the usage.

Comment: What gung is asking is if you have the value at 1 pm and 3 pm on a particular day, do you want to estimate usage at 2 pm for that day, or do you just want to treat is as empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd split *time* variable to hours, days, months. Convenient and quick way is using regular expressions, for example

```
hour <- str_extract(rl, ' [[:digit:]]{2}')
hour <- substring(hour, 2)
day <- str_extract(rl, '-[[:digit:]]{2} ')
day <- substring(day, 2, 3)
```

Then we need to cope with *value* being in cumulated form, reverse *cumsum* with *diff* (both from base R):

```
value <- diff(value)
```

Aggregated data for one of barplots created with data.table syntax

```
data[ , .(avg = mean(value)), by=.(house, day)]
```

or by using aggregate(base), which looks more readable

```
aggregate(data, value ~ house + day, mean)
```

Comment: what makes `aggregate` more readable than `data.table` syntax here, exactly?

Comment: @Arun: For me, the reason is clarity of formula notation and less parentheses. Data.table doesn't state whats being done (aggregation) explicitly, while this is first and most visible thing in base R aggregate function.

Comment: Pafnucy, but it's very limited in its functionality. I'm not sure, but how can we provide column names like `avg = `? How can we compute both `mean` and `median` or on multiple columns, for example, under the same interface? I think it's better to think in terms of the compromise in syntax *given the functionality*. I'm not sure if the formula interface is sufficient for all scenarios.. (haven't used it in a long time). I think, `.()` is a very small price to pay for readability, when it comes feature packed... imho.

Comment: But `diff(value)` returns something 1 element shorter than the original value, so I can't store that back into the value-field.